# tightvnc, belkin router, port 4900 open, still cant connect

Tags: ubuntu, windows-7, vnc

My computer on a private LAN, which connects to a router, which is connected to the internet.

Their computer is behind a belkin wireless router. I have turned the firewall and AV off for the computer that I am trying to connect to. I have also gone into the router settings and opened port 5900. (to clarify : the setting seems to be a mapping of her LAN IP to the port number. The checkmark for 'enabled' is checked, and it is her correct LAN IP address, and 5900 is the port)

I installed TightVNC server on their windows 7 computer, and it is running as a service. I am using ubuntus Remmina Remote Desktop Client. I can connect to my local windows 7 machine just fine.

When I try to connect to theirs, it hangs at 'Connecting to...'

When they go to http://canyouseeme.org to check if the port is open from the outside, the test fails (it is not open). Something is blocking it somewhere, but I cant figure out what that is.

Comment: Are you trying to reach the Windows 7 PC through the Internet? Does the Belkin wireless router has a private or public IP? Please provide more information on the network side of the setup.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like they need to follow some basic troubleshooting steps

1. Can they connect to it from another computer within their network (verifying that it is indeed a listening service)
2. If not fix that problem first if so then it looks like the router is the issue.  I would assume you are looking for something like port forwarding not a mapping although router vendors seem to take quite a bit of liberty on those terms.  Step though the settings again and see if you can locate the problem.  You may have to refer to the user manual